# Why am I getting a JWT with a bunch of periods/dots back from Google OAuth?

Tags: jwt, google-oauth

In a web application I'm running, I suddenly started getting these odd tokens containing a huge string of periods at the end.

This happens even when I bypass my application code and call the function from the Google OAuth library directly.

Here's an example token:

```
ya29.c.Kp8BCgi0lxWtUt-_[Normal JWT stuff, redacted for security]yVvGk...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Could this be an upstream issue with Google OAuth? Has anyone else seen tokens like this?

Comment: Could you provide more information, such as your code?

Comment: Are you sure these are JWTs or just opaque access tokens? In the latter case it doesn't matter how many dots you get at the end of the string, as long as a verification library recognises the token as valid :)

Comment: I noticed this is still a thing.  Is Google planning on fixing their stuff or are we supposed to remove the placeholders/dots every time?

Answer (score 3):

Same here, it suddenly started. Had to remove them from the received token, now it works again.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem is on the Google server-side.  It's actually returning the JWT with the trailing "." chars.  I'm updating Chilkat to automatically trim the trailing "." chars if found before returning the JWT.

Answer (score 2):

Same with me. And it leads to `Error: Invalid login: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error` for my nodeMailer application.

Solved with the following code:

```
tokensCache.access_token = tokensCache.access_token.replace(/\.+$/, '');
```

Comment: same issue here. are we sure that there can't be dots in the middlenof the token that shoudn't be replaced?

Comment: just use rtrim()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that clients should be able to handle the token sizes declared in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#size. Also, tokens must be opaque to clients, meaning, assuming token start with "ya29.blabla" is wrong. Instead, the token must be parsed as a string encoded  Web-safe base64 which standard is https://www.base64encode.org/enc/safe/

Answer (score -4):

In fact the dots make no difference. You can still use the access_token to call apis. If you get an error response, you'd better check a further reason. Do you set the correct scope (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)? Does the
permission of the service account is right?

Comment: they do make a difference.  They invalidate the token.  Google needs to fix this.